# AngularJS only show first date div in loop (with updating array object)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to render a javascript object to a template in Angular ~1.2.24

Only the first occurence of item.day should be shown.

example object:

```
$scope.listtrail = [{
    day: '2015-08-15',
    id: 123,
    timestamp: '2015-08-15 12:23:12'
},{
    day: '2015-08-15',
    id: 122,
    timestamp: '2015-08-15 12:43:34'
},{
    day: '2015-08-15',
    id: 121,
    timestamp: '2015-08-15 14:12:56'
},{
    day: '2015-08-14',
    id: 120,
    timestamp: '2015-08-14 11:12:09'
},{
    day: '2015-08-14',
    id: 118,
    timestamp: '2015-08-14 10:11:02'
}]
```

example template section:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listtrail">
    <div>{{item.day}}</div>
    <div>{{item.timestamp}}</div>
</div>
```

example template output goal:

```
<div>
    <div>2015-08-15</div>
    <div>2015-08-15 12:23:12</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>2015-08-15 12:43:34</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>2015-08-15 14:12:56</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>2015-08-14</div>
    <div>2015-08-14 11:12:09</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>2015-08-14 10:11:02</div>
</div>
```

Please note that the javascript array also gets prepended (as it grows) every few seconds using an internal splice function (just to bear in mind).

Comment: Can you post the full example please.

Comment: Does the JS object have to be an array, or can you make it a JSON object?

Comment: @danielrsmith not able to post the entire code as it's tied into a much larger full application. I have however editted the above code to illustrate the example object, ng-repeat and final output required.

Comment: @UltraSonja it is a JSON object during transport from rest service, stored back to a local var which due to it's recurrence is now an array of objects.

Comment: Seems to work just fine in an isolated example: https://jsfiddle.net/2o5nwy2r/3/

Comment: @danielrsmith Only the first occurence of item.day should be shown as per the example output. (that's the hard part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listtrail">
  <div ng-if="listtrail[$index-1].day != item.day">{{item.day}}</div>
  <div>{{item.timestamp}}</div>
 </div>
```

This should work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2o5nwy2r/5/

However using a $filter to do some sort of groupBy on the ng-repeat might be more resilient. Take a look at angular-filter https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Answer (score 2):

Nice solution would be to use [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module.
It could be then coded as:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in listtrail | groupBy: 'day'">
        <div>{{ key }}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="item in value">{{item.timestamp}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just take a look at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vs8p6sc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to match with previous day value

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listtrail">
  <div ng-if='listtrail[$index -1].day != item.day'>{{item.day}}</div>
  <div>{{item.timestamp}}</div>
</div>
```

You need to keep your records in order of day :)

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsvzbdrk/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same answer as the other two, but with the additional check for `$index == 0`:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in listtrail">
      <div ng-if="$index == 0 || listtrail[$index-1].day != item.day" ng->{{item.day}}</div>
      <div>{{item.timestamp}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not checking doesn't appear to cause an error, but it offends my sensibilities.

https://jsfiddle.net/2o5nwy2r/6/